# Use Variables for key in Jinja Render method

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to iterate over a dictionary and then use the dictionary items to render the template using Jinja.

```
for key,value in dict.values()
     out = template.render(key=value)
```

I am using undefined=DebugUndefined so that i can use multiple template renders without overwriting the placeholders.

The issue i am facing is that Jinja expects the exact string being passed to the render and i am not able to use the dictionary key. Jinja is trying to find the text {{ key }} for replacement.

Is there a a way I can pass in a variable as the key?

Comment: Thanks that helped. I was able to use template.render(**dict1) to render the template using a dictionary. Another thing i found while working on this was the use of multiple dictionaries,
i.e template.render(dict1=dict1, **dict2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build the dictionary and pass it as a kwargs:

```py
out = template.render(**{key: value})
```